# Horizontal multi level menu

Tags: css, menu

https://jsfiddle.net/ccaf8msu/1/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="first leaf"><a href="/front">Frontpage</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/library" class="container-one">Library</a></li>
<li class="expanded active-trail active"><a href="/om-websitet" class="active-trail active">About the website</a>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="first leaf"><a href="/en-sode">About the book</a></li>
      <li class="last leaf"><a href="/en-sode">The authors</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/categories" class="container-two">Categories</a></li>
<li class="last leaf webshop-link"><a href="http://google.dk">Webshop</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I have this 2 levels menu, and want both levels be horizontal as shown. The issue is when second level is active, and menu item 'about the website' gets a lot of whitespace after the item.

What i need is to get rid of the whitespace, and positioned the 2.level menu items to the right

Answer (score 0):

There's a whitespace because your dropdown is 1) after the `<li>` in the DOM order but 2) still takes up space before it goes to the next `<li>`.

What you need to do is set your dropdowns to have `position: absolute` so that it doesn't move your other elements around.

Also, in 2016, it's probably best to avoid floats and use `flexbox` for your layouts as it is much more powerful.

Here's a working code without white space:

**CSS:**

```
nav.navbar-default {
    width: 100%; 
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

ul li {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
}

.navbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    height: 55px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

And here's the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccaf8msu/2/).

Comment: The flex-direction: flex-start is giving me issues on chrome. invalid property value.

Answer (score 0):

Add style to li `position:relative` and inner ul `position:absolute`

```
nav.navbar-default {
    width: 100%;  
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
li ul{
    position:absolute
}
li a {
  display: block;
  height: 55px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```